Fill value from previous date if current date is not availables
I have two tables - sales and currency_rate. I want to fill col CurrRate to each transaction line from Sales based on the the month as from table sales col [Date] and table currency_rate col CurrentPeriod. If it happens that chain of dates is break in the table currency_rate I want to fill previous CurrRate value of previous month to the actual line of Sales. What is worth to mention that both CurrentPeriod and PreviousPeriod are datetime and Date in table Sales is int like 20240701
Snippet from Sales



Date
Value




20230404
1226.55


20230506
8.00


20230717
13834.73


20230916
10120.71


20230904
8.00


20230506
102.14


20230912
8.00


20230526
12813.40


20230805
779.90



Snippet from currency_rate (lets pretend one period is null)



CurrentPeriod
PreviousPeriod
CurrRate




2023-04-01T00:00:00.0000000
(NULL)
0.894166


2023-05-01T00:00:00.0000000
2023-04-01T00:00:00.0000000
0.893192


2023-06-01T00:00:00.0000000
2023-05-01T00:00:00.0000000
0.879856


2023-07-01T00:00:00.0000000
2023-06-01T00:00:00.0000000
0.887729


(NULL)
2023-07-01T00:00:00.0000000
0.896162


2023-09-01T00:00:00.0000000
2023-08-01T00:00:00.0000000
0.898093



Expected Result:



Date
Value
CurrRate




20230404
1226.55
0.894166


20230506
8.00
0.893192


20230717
13834.73
0.887729


20230916
10120.71
0.898093


20230904
8.00
0.898093


20230506
102.14
0.893192


20230912
8.00
0.898093


20230526
12813.40
0.893192


20230805
779.90
0.887729



As you can see 20230805 has value of 0.887729 which belongs to 2023-07-01T00:00:00.0000000 as its the previous period from 08 of 2023 year
Currently what I've done is to get PreviousPeriod to currency_rate using LAG function.
My one wonder is - if LAG should be ORDER BY CurrentPeriod ASC or DESC? Currently its ASC but I don't know if it should be DESC - any thoughs on that topic?
How to make join using spark.sql (can be in T-SQL i'll transpile it into spark) so I can get appropriate curr rates, even if I have NULLS in dates (not expected but better cover it now than going back when something fail). To cover the data type conversion for join I used
date_format(rates.currentperiod, 'yyyyMM') = date_format(to_date(cast(sales.date as string), 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyyMM')

Any help would be really appreciated
My query
SELECT
    inv.*
    IFNULL(cr.CurrRate, 0) AS CurrencyRate
FROM
    v_sales inv
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        CurrentPeriod,
        LAG(CurrentPeriod) OVER (PARTITION BY curr_rate_from, curr_rate_to ORDER BY CurrentRate) AS PreviousPeriod,
        curr_rate_from,
        curr_rate_to,
        CurrRate
    FROM
        schema.currency_rate
) cr ON
    inv.curr_code = cr.curr_rate_from -- not that important
    AND (
        (date_format(to_date(cast(inv.Day AS STRING), 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyyMM') = date_format(cr.CurrentPeriod, 'yyyyMM'))
        OR
        (date_format(to_date(cast(inv.Day AS STRING), 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyyMM') < date_format(cr.CurrentPeriod, 'yyyyMM') 
        AND date_format(to_date(cast(inv.Day AS STRING), 'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyyMM') >= date_format(cr.PreviousPeriod, 'yyyyMM'))
    )

I still have some 0's in the CurrencyRate, which shouldnt be the case

Could you provide your query and the result it currently provides to have something to work from?

I have added. Hope it helps

One option is to create a recursive cte to generate a sort of calendar of all the months from min to max date in sales table. If you are dealing with dates then it is most efficient to use date data types (not number or string). In the ansver below all date columns are truncated to a month.
Join sales and rates table to calendar cte taking care of null values and get your expected result:
WITH    -- recursive cte generating months for period of sales
  cal ( m_id, a_month, month_untill) AS
      ( Select 1 as m_id, month_from as a_month, month_untill
        From ( Select Min(TRUNC(To_Date(dat, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'MM')) as month_from, 
                    Max(TRUNC(To_Date(dat, 'yyyyMMdd'), 'MM')) as month_untill
               From sales
             )
       UNION ALL
        Select m_id + 1, ADD_MONTHS(a_month, 1), month_untill
        From   cal
        Where  a_month < month_untill
      )

... sales table here was Inner Joined - but if you want to see all the months of period (having sales or not - Jun 2023 no sales ) change it to Left Join and use Coalesce() and type coonversion to get date from calendar instead of sales date. Rates table was Left Joined to the calendar and if there is no current period date the previous one is taken using Coalesce() function...
--    S Q L : 
Select     s.dat, s.val,
           Coalesce(cr.rate, LAG(cr.rate) Over(Order By cal.a_month)) as rate
From       cal  
Inner Join sales s ON( Trunc(To_Date(SubStr(s.dat, 1, 10), 'yyyyMMdd'), 'MM')  = cal.a_month )
Left Join currency_rate cr ON( Coalesce(Trunc(cr.currentperiod, 'MM'), Trunc(cr.previousperiod, 'MM')) = cal.a_month )
Order By  cal.a_month, s.dat


/*    R e s u l t :
       DAT        VAL       RATE
---------- ---------- ----------
  20230404    1226.55   0.894166   
  20230506          8   0.893192   
  20230506     102.14   0.893192   
  20230526    12813.4   0.893192   
  20230717   13834.73   0.887729   
  20230805      779.9   0.887729   
  20230904          8   0.898093   
  20230912          8   0.898093   
  20230916   10120.71   0.898093    */


Quick Answer
Look below for a quick comment on your query.
Note: To make the example easy I already assume all dates are equally formatted as dates, you may have to adapt to your table schemas.
You have a good approach where you first try to clean up the rates table and then join on a date range, but you're just missing a few details when cleaning up the table, here is a possible solution:
WITH FilledRates AS (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN CurrentPeriod IS NOT NULL THEN CurrentPeriod
             ELSE LEAD(PreviousPeriod, 1) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        END AS current_period,
        PreviousPeriod as previous_period,
        CurrRate as curr_rate
    FROM currency_rate
),

RateRange AS (
    SELECT
        start_period,
        CASE WHEN end_period IS NULL THEN DATEADD(month, 1, start_period)
             ELSE end_period 
        END AS end_period,
        curr_rate
    FROM (
        SELECT
            current_period AS start_period,
            LEAD(current_period, 1) OVER (ORDER BY current_period ASC) AS end_period,
            curr_rate
        FROM FilledRates
    ) AS RateRangeWithNullEnd
)

SELECT
    s.*
    rr.curr_rate
FROM v_sales s
LEFT OUTER JOIN RateRange rr 
    ON s.sale_date > rr.start_period AND s.sale_date < rr.end_period;

This is actually similar to your approach, the main differences are:

FilledRates: Use LEAD to look to the next previous_period to fill in current_period when it is null, this ensures no null current_period
RateRange: Change the rates table to a table where each record has the start and end date for the given range with no null values, this ensures an easy join moving forward. And also helps join the dates on the last period. Note: I am assuming empty dates can be filled with a DATEADD statement where we add a month. You didn't indicate any specific rule here, but I will assume intervals are consistent in length.
Result: The join is quite similar to what you already have, but we now the table we join in has the start and end period for each rate.

Notes
In the statement:
SELECT
        CurrentPeriod,
        LAG(CurrentPeriod) OVER (PARTITION BY curr_rate_from, curr_rate_to ORDER BY CurrentRate) AS PreviousPeriod,
        curr_rate_from,
        curr_rate_to,
        CurrRate
    FROM
        schema.currency_rate

By using LAG you are looking one record ahead, but based on your example, a record ahead can be null (line 5 from the currency_rate table). Because you are ordering by CurrentPeriod, this will result in your currency rates for any period after the first null value to not be linked to the correct periods.
